# Unable to SSH to GCE instance

Tags: apache-2.2

Unable to SSH to GCE instance

Till yesterday my SSH connection via Filezilla was working fine, it was just while transfering some files to server my internet connection broke twice. then again i tried to connect it gives me the below error.

Error:  FATAL ERROR: Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
Error:  Could not connect to server

Answer (score 0):

I would try connecting via the commandline

```
gcloud compute ssh --vv --project PROJECT_ID --zone ZONE VM_NAME

ssh -v *ip of your gcp instance*
```

As well what is it showing in your google cloud console? Is the server turned on?